# PHP Zend engine compile the code or interpreters it

Tags: php

As per wikipedia:

> Scripts are loaded into memory and compiled into Zend opcodes

One line below is said:

> The interpreter part analyzes the input code, translates it, and
>   executes it.

As I know the code is loaded in the memory, then goes through lexical analyze, getting parsed and compiled to opcodes. I fall in total mess even after ton of articles about the engine. So in the end is PHP code compiled or interpretered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the distinction between "compiling" and "interpreting" is less clear in practice than Computer Science lessons would imply, as is the distinction between a "runtime environment" and a "virtual machine".

The answer is essentially that it is *both*: the Zend Engine first *compiles* your PHP code to an intermediate representation called "opcodes"; it then *interprets* these opcodes to execute the code.

In some ways, this is similar to the way Java is first compiled to bytecode, and then executed on the Java Virtual Machine; however, the "VM" which executes the code in the Zend Engine is not defined like a real processor, and is closely tied to the PHP language. It therefore acts more like a traditional interpreter, but of a language that no human would write.

Comment: Thank you very much! The second paragraph explained it very clear. Wish that I can see such clear answers more frequently...

Answer (score 0):

> The Zend Engine is responsible for the following tasks in PHP:
>
> High performance parsing (including syntax checking), **in-memory compilation** and execution of PHP scripts [..]

Source: http://www.zend.com/products/zend_engine/in_depth